# How do I use and configure miraclecast when installed

Tags: command-line, compiling

I have compiled and installed miraclecast, and I have my terminal inside the miraclecast-master/build folder, I just finished `make install` but now I do not know how to open it because I don't see any miraclecast program anywhere so how do I use and configure it now?

(And how can i mirror it to my LG Smart TV?)

Comment: I suppose it's [this](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast) – so you didn't just use [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/miraclecast)?

Comment: no i but i want to use it to mirror to my LG Smart TV

Comment: OK, well if you already succesfully(!) installed it then just follow [the documentation](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast#documentation), it has been installed in `/usr/local` if nothing went wrong.

Comment: when i type miracled nothing happens

Comment: Why do you think this command should work? The documentation mentions `miracle-wifid` and `miracle-sinkctl` only – I may miss something here though, please explain!

Comment: i did ls /usr/local

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69072/discussion-between-dessert-and-yoran-jansen).

Comment: @YoranJansen Did you make it with the help from @dessert?  I have installed it from PPA and did not make it. I get to have on my Samsung TV a message with "connecting to laptop-id", but nothing happens from there.

Comment: @conualfy I have some problems too but I think it is better to go to https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast/issues for those.